# Prove that $n-$cube is $n-$connected

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

The $n-$cube, $Q_n$ , is defined by: $Q_1 = K_2$ and $Q_n = Q_{n+1} \times K_2$ for $n \geq 2$.

I have to prove that for $n \in \mathbf{N} \setminus\{0\}$, $Q_n$ is $n-$connected. I'm
trying to solve it by induction but I don't know how to proceed with the inductive step:

$\textbf{Base Case:}$ For $n = 1$, since $Q_1 = K_2$, $Q_1$ has two vertices, let $v \in V(Q_1)$, we can substract the adyacent vertex of $v$ and we get a trivial graph, then $\kappa(Q_1) = 1$ and $Q_1$ is $1-$connected.

$\textbf{Inductive Hipotesis:}$ For $n > 1$, every vertex $u \in V(Q_n)$ has $n$ neighbors, then $Q_n - N(u)$ is not connected and also, $|N(u)| = \kappa(Q_n)$. Thus $\kappa(Q_1) = n$ and $Q_n$ is $n-$connected.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a proof [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316086/vertex-connectivity-of-the-hypercube)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\kappa(Q_n) \le \delta(Q_n) = n$; the hard part is proving that $\kappa(Q_n) \ge n$. To do this, we can show that for any two vertices $u,v$ of $Q_n$, there are $n$ vertex-disjoint $u-v$ paths, assuming from the inductive hypothesis that there are $n-1$ such paths in $Q_{n-1}$.

There are two cases for $u$ and $v$:

- If there is a copy of $Q_{n-1}$ containing both of them, then we can find $n-1$ paths inside that copy. For the last path, let $u'$ and $v'$ be the neighbors of $u$ and $v$ respectively in the other copy of $Q_{n-1}$. Go from $u$ to $u'$, take some path from $u'$ to $v'$ in the other copy of $Q_{n-1}$ (there's at least $n-1$ to choose from), and then go from $v'$ to $v$.
- If there is no such copy, then $u$ and $v$ are opposite vertices of $Q_n$, and this case is symmetric to having $u = (0,0,0,\dots,0)$ and $v = (1,1,1,\dots,1)$. Here, I'm treating the vertices of $Q_n$ as $\{0,1\}^n$. We can explicitly give $n$ vertex-disjoint $u-v$ paths. Let the first path be $(v_0, v_1, \dots, v_n)$ where $v_i = (\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_i, \underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}_{n-i})$; for the other paths, cyclically rotate the vertices of this one.